# Waitress asks question with different tense

Tags: grammar, tenses

Suppose a scenario that I want to have dinner in a restaurant, when I come into the restaurant, a waitress asks me the question whether I have a reservation. The way of asking can be as follows:

> 1) Do you have a reservation?
>
> 2) Have you made a reservation?
>
> 3) Did you make a reservation?
>
> 4) Have you had a reservation?

I have learned **1)** and **2)** from textbook, and then I write **3)** and **4)** myself. I know that all of them are grammatically correct. But what I want to know is what the differences among these sentences are.

P.S. I am not a English native speaker, but a English learner.

Answer (score 3):

1) A straight-forward question of whether there currently and presently is in existance a current reservation for the person.

2) A question of whether the person has made a reservation, and theoretically could include cancelled reservations. It is somewhat elliptical, however, implying making a reservation *for today/now*.

3) Same as sentence 2, except that it is in the simple past tense rather than present perfect. There is no difference in meaning.

4) This is a bit of a strange one. This asks whether the person has in the past held a reservation, using the past perfect. It doesn't sound like the waitress would be asking about a current reservation, rather, oddly, about a previous reservation in the past that probably was a no-show.

Comment: (1) is what you would be asked by a waitress or receptionist. (2) is more likely to be used by a wife asking a husband whether he's called the restaurant yet. (3) is possible at a restaurant, but unlikely, since it's about the past leading to the present. (4) is completely out, because it's completely about the past -- it asks about previous reservations, not the current one.

Comment: Ah! Of course; I completely forgot that use of the 2nd one. The 3rd one would for me then be when the couple arrive at the restaurant and the wife is worried that her husband has forgotten to make a reservation.

'Did you make a reservation?!'
'Yes darling, I did.'

Or vice versa, depending on the competency of the man (usually!).

Comment: Deonyi @John Lawler Thanks for you guys. Let's focus the situation on the dialog between waitress and I instead of between a couple.  Now, I know that **1)** is the most appropriate and **4)** is NOT appropriate or even wrong since it asks the reservation of the past and I know the reason now.

Comment: As for **2)** and **3)**, Say I called the restaurant for reservation 30 minutes ago before I came into it. Now I am standing at the counter, and the waitress asks me with **2)** or **3)**. And I reply *Yes, I have.* or *Yes, I did.* accordingly.  Are they right?

Comment: Yes, but those are unlikely for the waitress. If you have made a reservation, then you **have** a reservation, and that's the important thing. Naturally you had to make it, but having it is the state that continues into the present time, and tense.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes. I have had a reservation since I made one in the past. When we did an action in the past, it sometimes created or changed the state and then the state lasts or continues from the past into the present. It is general and ubiquitous. That's the reason why I ask this question.

Comment: Specifically for this question, I have a reservation which is a **state** of present. So one can ask it with **)1** by means of **Present Simple**. Accordingly, one can ask its **action** which one did in the past with **2)** and **3)** by **Present Perfect** and **Past Simple**. Thus, I think to myself when one asks the same question with different tenses,  the meanings could be almost the same.

Comment: To be honest, they all mostly mean the same thing, however each focusses on a slightly different action or state in the overall process of making a reservation.